# how to draw line with two images using mouse and also how to drag this line with images using javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to draw a line between the images using mouse but when I drag, the line is nor properly dragged.

```
public class line1 extends Application {
    final Image image1=new Image("image/MME.png");

    final Image image2=new Image("image/HSS.png");
     final ImageView i1=new ImageView();
     final ImageView i2=new ImageView();
        Line line;

            @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
          final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
          i1.setImage(image1);
          i1.setLayoutX(200);
          i1.setLayoutY(300);
          i2.setImage(image2);
          i2.setLayoutX(50);
          i2.setLayoutY(50);
          i1.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);


         root.getChildren().addAll(i1,i2);
         root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                  double x = event.getX();
                  double y = event.getY();
                  line = new Line(x, y, x, y);
                  root.getChildren().add(line);
                               }
        });
        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                      line.setEndX(event.getX());
                       line.setEndY(event.getY());
                   }
        });
        i1.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                 line.setStartX(event.getScreenX());
                 line.setStartY(event.getScreenY());    
                 line.setEndX(i2.getLayoutX());
                 line.setEndY(i2.getLayoutY());
                 i1.setLayoutX(event.getScreenX());
                 i1.setLayoutY(event.getScreenY());
                 root.getChildren().add(line);
             }
             });


          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1350, 850));
          primaryStage.show();
     }

         public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```